# Show that this probability distribution can be approximated by a Gaussian.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, normal-distribution

I have this distribution

$P_{N}(L)=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{N-1}(N-1)!}{(\frac{L}{a}-1)!(N-\frac{L}{a})!}$,

where $L∈\{a,2a,3a...Na\}$. It can be shown that $\sum_{L∈\{a,2a,3a...Na\}}P_{N}(L)=1$.

I need to show that $P_{N}$ can be approximated by a Gaussian function for large N and obtain the proper normalization constant. How can I do that? I tried to apply the natural logarithm at both sides so I could do a Taylor expansion, but I got stuck. One approximation could be:

$P_{N}(L)=(\frac{N}{2(N-y)})^{N}(\frac{N-y}{y})^{y}$,
where $y=\frac{L}{a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L = a (K+1)$, you have $P_N(L) = 2^{-N+1} {N-1 \choose K}$, $K = 0 \ldots N-1$, which in terms of $K$ is the binomial distribution with parameters $N-1$ and $1/2$.  The de Moivre-Laplace theorem (or, if you prefer, the Central Limit Theorem), gives you the desired approximation.